# Bizarre class inheritance issue in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, import, rspec

I am trying to run a test using rspec on a class i just wrote which inherits from a parent class. The test is unable to find the parent class. However, when an almost identical test with the same parent class is run on other classes, its totally fine.

From what I can see, all of my imports are correct.

```
An error occurred while loading ./spec/queen_spec.rb.
Failure/Error:
NameError:
  uninitialized constant Piece
  class Queen < Piece
                ^^^^^
/spec/queen_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>
No examples found.
```

Here is the queen_spec file

```
# spec/queen_spec.rb
require_relative 'spec_helper'
```

spec_helper file

```
# spec/spec_helper.rb

$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib'))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))

require 'pieces/piece'
require 'pieces/pawn'
require 'pieces/rook'
require 'pieces/knight'
require 'pieces/queen'
```

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with the code you included. Can you provide a [mre] that allows us to replicate your problem?

Comment: Did you check the `Piece` class for typos?

Comment: You are going to have to provide more detail here. Can you show a basic synopsis of one of the requires that worked? Maybe you failed to namespace appropriately in the `Queen` file but did so in the others? For instance if I was building this chances are the full class name for `Queen` would be `Chess::Pieces::Queen` where `Chess` and `Pieces` were modules and the `Pieces` module provided a scope for `Piece`, `King`, `Queen`, etc.

Comment: Your posted code assumes `../lib/pieces.rb` exists and requires something that defines Piece. This may or may not be true.

Answer (score 0):

```
  class Queen < Piece
                ^^^^^
/spec/queen_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>
```

Your error is reported on line 1 of `queen_spec.rb`, which means you're trying to use `Piece` before your `require_relative 'spec_helper'`, ie. before your `require 'pieces/piece'` - ie. before `Piece` is defined.  QED

*Side note:* your `lib` and your `spec` folders should already be in your `$LOAD_PATH`